# Jersey 2.5: How can a resource access external classes instances

Tags: java, jersey-2.0

I have embedded Jetty container inside my main server and I also use Jersey 2.5 for handling REST resources.

everything seems to work well and now I would like to pass my server's context class into each of my REST resources.

I'm having hard time understanding how to do that...

If someone can provide full code example - it could be awesome!

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean when you say you have a Jetty container inside your "main server"? Are you programmatically executing Jetty within the application? Also, when you say "context" are you referring to the ServletContext?

Comment: YES - I have my "main server" that runs using Apache MINA as far as connections manager and during its initialization it creates an instance of Jetty HTTP Container (JettyHttpContainerFactory instance) all in single JVM.

When I say "context" I mean my "main server"  interface and not ServletContext. I would like to pass\inject an interface of my "main server" into the REST resources so every resource will have access to services provided by my "main server".

Does it make sense or there is something "BIG" that I'm missing??